# jquery share $(this) between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two click events that are almost identical, I am trying to refactor to make it more DRY. I want share some lines of code in a handlerShared() function - but I loose the context of $(this) which should be the DOM element that is clicked. There are two different elements an svg and button. They have some specific functionality but alot of it is the same. I guess what I want is a way to make $(this) select the specific DOM element.

```
    function handelerShared() {
        
    }

    function handlerTabs() {
        var $this = $(this)
        var dataKey = $this.attr("data-key");
        pushHistory(dataKey);
        removeActiveClass();
        hideContent();
        $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

    function handlerDiagram() {
        var $this = $(this)
        var dataKey = $this.attr("data-key")
        pushHistory(dataKey);
        removeActiveClass();
        hideContent();
        scrollToTabs();
        $(themeTab + "." + dataKey).addClass(activeClass);
        var activeSVGTab =  $(themeContent + "." + dataKey)
        $(activeSVGTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
```

I m try to take these lines of of each handler and out into a handlerShared()

```
        var $this = $(this)
        var dataKey = $this.attr("data-key");
        pushHistory(dataKey);
        removeActiveClass();
        hideContent();
```

the clicks

```
$(themeTab).on( "click", handlerTabs );
$(themeDiagram).on( "click", handlerDiagram );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just pass the element around:

```
function handlerShared(element) {
  var $this = $(element);
  var dataKey = $this.attr("data-key");
  pushHistory(dataKey);
  removeActiveClass();
  hideContent();
}

function handlerTabs() {
  handlerShared(this);
  $(this).addClass(activeClass);
  var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
}

function handlerDiagram() {
  handlerShared(this);
  scrollToTabs();
  $(themeTab + "." + dataKey).addClass(activeClass);
  var activeSVGTab =  $(themeContent + "." + dataKey)
  $(activeSVGTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
}

$(themeTab).on("click", handlerTabs);
$(themeDiagram).on("click", handlerDiagram);
```

Comment: Thanks.... jeez I got it 1min after asking. Thanks, always happens, I ask the question then seem to work it out lol.